# Filter all nodes where the property defined in Beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

It's easy to filter on some node property in bs4:

```
doc_soup.find_all('simpleType', {name: 'k'})
```

How can I find all the node where property defined(regardless value)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the attribute value to `True` which would basically check for *attribute presence*:

```
doc_soup.find_all('simpleType', {name: True})
```